# Redux - dispatch is undefined in action

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo, redux-thunk

I'm new to redux, but i have a problem that i don't understand and it can not fix it.

***The problem is, when i want to dispatch inside my action, I've got an error who said :***

> dispatch is not a function

Yep, he is undefined and this is the point, why he is undefined ?

```js
export const clearError = dispatch => {
    console.log('clear error')
    console.log(dispatch)

    dispatch({
        type: 'CLEAR_ERROR'
    })
}
```

I call the ***clearError*** action from **Main.js**, maybe my initialization is not correct, but i've tried several way, like *bindActionCreators*...

**Main.js (how i pass props and dispatch with connect)**

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    clearError: clearError
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Main)
```

I'm really confused because in other component I use two others actions made by the same way and everything it's ok...

I don't know if it can help you to understand the origin of the problem but i show you how i configure the store to call **configureStore()** in App.js.

```js
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers'

const configureStore = () => {
    const middleware = [thunk]
    return createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware))
}

export default configureStore
```

I'm listening every help and advices about redux and the best way to use it !

Really thanks to you for reading ❤️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are not returning a function from your action creator with `dispatch` as one of the arguments:

```js
export const clearError = () => dispatch => {
```

Under the hood, when you pass your action creators to mapDispatchToProps, Redux "maps" that dispatch argument to your action creators, and then assigns the mapped action creators to Component properties.
This is also why you have to call `this.props.clearError()` instead of just `clearError()`.

Comment: Nice answer, it works perfectly, thank you.
But i don't understand, in which case we have to use ** bindActionCreators** ?

Comment: `bindActionCreators` is another way of accomplishing the same thing as `mapDispatchToProps`. You can read more about the potential use cases in the docs: https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators